# Delete a resource from external API from destroy action in Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, controllers

I'm figuring out how can I delete some resource from an external API from destroy action in Rails controller.

to delete this resource I have to do this, actually I have this code in a Concern in controllers folder:

### Concern

```
def unsubscribe_user
  @external_api = ExternalApi.new(@key1, @key2)

  @subscription = @external_api.create(:subscription)
  # subscription_id and client_id are stored in my DB as an "historical" record
  @unsubscribed = @subscription.delete(subscription_id, client_id)
end
```

### Controller

```
def destroy
  unsubscribe_user

  if @unsubscribed.nil?
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully unsubscribed..."
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "An error has ocurred..."
      redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

sooo, in my view I have:

```
<p>Unsubscribe <%= button_to "Cancel my Subscription", suscription_path, {:action => :delete} %> </p>
```

Rails needs an ID to delete a resource from DB (for example: subscription_path(current_user.id)), so, I don't have this resource in my local DB, there is no ID to pass. I only need to execute this Concern code in the destroy action. How can I do that?

### Edit

I forget to put routes:

```
resources :subscribe, except: :edit
```

Comment: what are your routes for this one?

Comment: `resources :subscribe, except: :edit`

Answer (score 0):

just use a fake id like 1, or you can use some other route config for this action

Comment: For example, link to unsubscribe would be `<%= button_to "Cancel my Subscription", subscription_path(current_user), {:action => :delete} %>`, so, I'm passing the user ID = 1 and I'm getting **No route matches [POST] "/subscriptions/1"**

Answer (score 0):

Use the singular resource in your routes:

```
resource :subscribe, except: :edit
```

Then in your `rake routes` you can see that you don't need an id argument